# What's wrong in this user's reputation?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

Look at [this user's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1834977/gnanasekaran-kuppusamy). I found that his reputation is 11. But actually his question got 3 upvotes (without any downvote). I think his reputation should be 16.

Look at the screen shots captured while asking this question.

> [image]

Note: While asking this question that user got another upvote so his total reputation was became 16. Shouldn't it be 21?

He is only 9 days old. So there is no chance that we miss very old points. An this user has only [1 question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fy6S0.png) at a time of asking this question.

Comment: now he just got +2 for accepting an answer

Comment: Reputation looks right now; must have something to do with the deletion of one his/her answers.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ - Yep. Now reputation looks perfect. But why was his/her reputation not updated at that time?

Comment: Maybe you just hit that page right as the DB was getting updated? Or there is a delay on [the deleted answer (10K link)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13578361/331508) cleanup?

Comment: @AwesomePoodles - Actually when I posted this question, his/her reputation was not updated as per his votes. That issue remain for more than 20-25 minutes. The users who agree with this question also watched that.

Comment: Then maybe there is a delay on the job that reverses scores for deleted answers.  He has one that got +10 and -2 rep.

Comment: @AwesomePoodles - Between those 20-25 minutes he got upvotes on his question, he also added an answer for thanking after I posted this question. He got 1 downvote and 1 upvote at that time. So his rep. increased by 8. But he still missed 5 rep. at that time.

Answer (score 2):

An answer of his was deleted.  When this happens the reputation adjustment is lagged by up to 5 minutes (it's a job that runs every 5 minutes, could be instant, could be 5 minutes, depends where it fell in the interval).

The answer was deleted just before you saw this which means it was in that window, shortly after your port all was right with the world, carry on.

Comment: Actually, he posted the answer after I posted this question. Please look my [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156802/whats-wrong-in-this-users-reputation/156819#comment451866_156802) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156802/whats-wrong-in-this-users-reputation/156819#comment451871_156802) comment. (You can confirm that by seeing the time of that deleted answer.)